# How to download image from asynchronously in swift

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uiimageview, swift2, uicollectionview

Hi I am developing a app using swift2.2 am getting a data from a server and am passing it to the collection view.am getting more images from the server i cant pass it very quickly it consumes so much of time so i need to to pass that quickly as much as possible.

code in my view controller:

```
 func jsonParsingFromURL() {

    self.view.makeToastActivity(.Center)
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
      Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://something.com=\(appDelCityname)&fromLimit=0&toLimit=20", parameters: nil, encoding: .URL, headers: nil).response {
        (req, res, data, error) - > Void in
          let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(dataString)

        let json = JSON(data: data!)
        let jsonData = json["ad_count"].int
        if jsonData == 0 {
          let alert = UIAlertController(title: "sorry!", message: "No Ads availabe", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
          alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
          self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
          self.startParsing(data!)
        }
      }
    } else {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "make sure your device is connected to the internet", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
      self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

  }

  func startParsing(data: NSData) {
    let json = JSON(data: data)
    let mainArr = json["subcategory"].array!
      for item in mainArr {
        self.fetchImage = item["images"].stringValue
        self.fetchPrice = item["originalprice"].stringValue
        self.fetchTitle = item["adtitle"].stringValue
        self.fetchCityname = item["districtname"].stringValue
        let takefirstImg = self.fetchImage.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
        let firstimgofStr = takefirstImg[0]

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
          () - > Void in
          let URL_API_HOST2: String = "https://www.something.com"
          let url = NSURL(string: URL_API_HOST2 + firstimgofStr)
          let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
          let imageyy = UIImage(data: data!)
          self.priceArr.append(self.fetchPrice)
          self.cityArr.append(self.fetchCityname)
          self.adtitleArr.append(self.fetchTitle)
          print("something = \(firstimgofStr)")
          print("check image = \(self.fetchTitle)")
          self.imageDict.append(imageyy!)
          self.view.hideToastActivity()
        })
        self.refresh()
      }

  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) - > Int {
    return imageDict.count
  }
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("FilterCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!SecondTableViewCell

    cell.FifTitle.text = adtitleArr[indexPath.item]
    cell.FifAddress.text = cityArr[indexPath.item]
    cell.Fifprice.text = priceArr[indexPath.item]
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

      cell.Fifimage.image = self.imageDict[indexPath.item]

    })

    // cell.Fifimage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: URL_API_HOST2 + (firstImage as String)))

    return cell
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > CGSize {

    return imageDict[indexPath.item].size
  }
```

I am having the library of SDWebImage but which will allow only url type but i have to use UIImage value to calculate the size of image to get Pinterest style view.according to my method it works well but when i get more value from the server it makes very late to display so help me to work with this process am struggling from the morning.

Comment: Please refer to this famous third party library in order to perform elegant networking operations in Swift : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire. Check the Usage part.

Comment: does UIImage value mean image's height & width?

Comment: yes...@nikdange_me

Comment: yes..@nikdange_me..am following a method https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout